# Как выполнить код уже после открытия программы? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Раньше я всегда писал код тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и никогда не было никаких проблем с этим, до тех пор пока я не решился сделать таймер, и только сейчас я понял что код написанный тут запускаеться еще перед тем как `main.cpp` вызывает `return a.exec();` проблем добавило еще то что ui приватный класс и вызвать его в main.cpp невозможно, да и если бы возможно было бы это как то костыльно выглядело бы, так как же выполнить код после того как приложение откроеться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться таймером:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &MainWindow::startSlot);
```

Т.к. время срабатывания 0 миллисекунд `timerEvent` сработает, когда приложение войдёт в eventLoop.

Comment: QTimer не подходит под мои цели + вопрос заключался в том где писать код чтоб он запускался сразу при открытии программы а не в том как сделать таймер

Comment: @Selasi, код пишется в соответствующем таймеру слоте. Этот слот сработает один раз, когда будет вызван `a.exec()`. Почему вы считаете, что `QTimer` вам не подходит?

Comment: Кажись я не до конца понял вас, ваш ответ действительно являеться решением, спасибо за ответ